# Тормозит обновление Oxyplot графика в Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

Нужно вывести график в реальном времени, обновляемый раз в секунду. Проблема в том, что график обновляется только когда я меняю размер окна, в ином случае он просто не перерисовывается.

Wpf:

```
<Grid Name="grid" Margin="10,99,11.6,45.4">
    <oxy:Plot Name="Plot" Margin="10,0">
        <oxy:Plot.Series>
            <oxy:LineSeries Name="LineSeries" ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"/>
        </oxy:Plot.Series>
    </oxy:Plot>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
        line = new LineSeries() { };

        // заполнение List со значениями из БД
        double j = 0;
        for (int i = request_ListValueMessage.data.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            line.Points.Add(new DataPoint(j, Convert.ToDouble(request_ListValueMessage.data[i])));
            j++;
            Debug.WriteLine(j + " " + Convert.ToDouble(request_ListValueMessage.data[i]));
        }

        //прорисовка графика первый раз
        LineSeries.DataContext = line;

        //запуск таймера
        DispatcherTimer timer1 = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
        };
        timer1.Tick += ValueRequest;
        timer1.Start();
```

Метод в таймере:

```
    public void ValueRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client = new Client("127.0.0.1", 80);
        string LastValueMessage = client.message(3, new string[1] { ComboBoxChoiseSensors.Text });
        Request request = new Request(LastValueMessage);
        LastValue = Convert.ToDouble(request.data[0]); // получение нового значения

        //добавление нового значения в конец List
        line.Points.Add(new DataPoint(line.Points.Count + 1, LastValue));
        line.Points.RemoveAt(0); //удаление первого

        //обновление List
        double j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.Points.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            line.Points[i] = (new DataPoint(i, line.Points[i].Y));
            j++;
        }
    }
```

В Oxyplot разбираюсь плохо, укажите, пожалуйста, конкретно что и куда добавить.

Comment: Вероятно, вы не уведомляете контрол о том, что данные изменились. В WPF нет магии, в WPF есть интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` и соответствующее событие, на которое умеет автоматически подписываться `Binding`. Ну либо после обновления данных нужно принудительно сообщить контролу, чтобы он перерисовался. Попробуйте [вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927669/how-to-refresh-oxyplot-plot-when-data-changes).

Comment: Спасибо! Ссылка, которую вы дали очень помогла!